# Git | Branching model for a large project

Tags: git, version-control

Our team has three back-end developers and two front-end developers. We're using `Git` as a version control system, `Jira` for issue and project tracking, and `Stash` as a Git repository. And finally, we're using `SourceTree` (with `git-flow`) as Git client.

The problem is about our branching strategy: We're using Vincent Driessen's [branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Everyone creates a `feature branch` for each issue and merge it back to `develop` when it's done (via pull request and after a review on Stash). Other than that, we create `bugfix branches` for finished but not yet released issues, `hotfix branches` for released issues and `release branches` for finished sprints. No-one touches `develop` and/or `master` directly in this scenario. Our front-end team uses `Sass` as CSS pre-processor. And finally, we have `TeamCity` to build changes, and it looks for the changes on `master` branch.

---

Enough with the back-story, huh? Okay then, here's the problem: Let's say we have 50 issues in the sprint (10 for each of us), and at the end of the sprint, client wants to release only 35 of them (no need to ask why, it's the client). So, we need to exclude 15 issues somehow. Mostly, they are front-end issues. And because of our setup, everything is on `develop` branch at this moment. We have couple of alternatives now:

- Creating a `release branch` from `develop` and reverting those 15 issues (we need to either update TeamCity, or merge this branch back to `master` afterwards).
- Putting everything to `master` reverting on there (no need to touch TeamCity in this scenario).
- Cherry picking wanted issues onto `master` (this will probably end up with lots of conflicts as well).

But both of them has this restriction: Sass-to-CSS operation. If we choose the first option, and there're some front-end issues, there'll be a conflict for sure. If we choose the second option, we're loosing track of what is where and I think this is kind of abuse in the end.

And there's this big global restriction: We need to do our tests on `develop` (so, every finished issue needs to be on `develop` to test, this can't change) and we're releasing what's on `master` (there's a way to change this in TeamCity, but no-one wants to change it).

**The question is this: How we can use Git continuously when there are some improvements and stoppage at the same time?**

*I can provide more details if you need, feel free to ask.*

Comment: Do you know which issues you are going to include in the release *before* starting your sprint, or is this decided at the end?

Comment: Can´t you do your tests in the bugfix and feature branches? Try to keep them up to date and when the issue is completed (development + test) and it is decided to release the changes merge them onto master.

Comment: @poke, no, we are thinking to release them all at the end, but there is this 3rd-parties that we need to get approval. Sometimes, they are being late about this.

Comment: @Jehof, sadly no, our test environment looks for the changes on `develop` only. Otherwise, it'll be a mess.

Comment: I assume you can’t hold off merging the features into develop until the decision has been made, right?

Comment: @poke, nope, no merge to develop equals no tests. In this case, we need to wait until the end of the sprint and make some room for code freeze + test phase. That's totally out of our cycle.

Comment: But if you only test on develop, and you only choose the actual features to include somewhere at the end of your sprint, that also means that the delivered features are never tested on their own but always combined with the other set of features. That’s just bad, and you should communicate that to your client so that it leaves you more time to stabilize the exact feature set you are going to deliver.

Comment: That's correct. Our setup is kinda weird and limits our work. But this is what we have. And yes, we need to test them together to see if they all are working correctly. Sometimes, changing one line breaks everything, I mean literally everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your problem well. I would see a 4th solution as more viable for your case:

- use `develop` the same as until now, having everything there, since you have to do your tests there
- set a `production` (or `release`) branch -> this will be your release branch, at least for now, until you can fully deploy everything (if your client will ever want that)
- since you said everything is on feature branches, you can easily merge these branches into the `production` one after they were tested on develop. Basically `develop` is your `qa` branch (for testing purposes). This is better than cherry-picking tens or hundreds of commits at the end of the sprint.

So what I'm basically suggesting is after merging the feature branches into `develop`, don't delete them, do eventual bugfixing related to a feature on that feature's branch, and then merge the branch into the `production` one.

Let me know if you think there are reasons why this approach won't work (apart from the fact that you have to change the release branch configuration).

Comment: Ah, that one looks promising. Back in time, we thought of creating a branch named `stable` and use it for production but people didn't want it because we can only replicate data from staging (which looks for `master`) to production. There's no direct touch to production environment. So, people started to questioning like "are we going to change TeamCity settings before each release?" or something. But I think this answer is acceptable in most of the cases.

Comment: Well you case is kinda weird, I guess. But you don't need to change configuration every time. You just release from the `stable` branch, and when the clients finally decide "Heck, we can release everthing", you change it back to master and continue with the classic branching strategy

Comment: I can create a new TeamCity configuration for `stable` branch, and we can hit the button when we have a partial release. I assume that'd simplify the usage on our side. Other than that, yes our case is really weird indeed.

Comment: It seems that this is the best way for us. Thanks for the advice, accepting this as an answer.